# NSIS script + Skip button alignment issue

Tags: nsis

I am trying NSIS script to add "SKIP" button.

I have tested  below code and it works well but when I actually integrate with the main code which is having a screen of option "back" "Next" and "Cancel" button. this skip button is not visible at all, it is in extreme right of cancel button and hardly visible.

How can move this "Skip" button towards left side.

```
Name BtnTest
Outfile test.exe
Installdir "$temp"
RequestExecutionLevel user
BrandingText " " ;Button covers this text
!include nsDialogs.nsh ;For WS_*
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT SKIP

Function SKIP
; You are supposed to use ChangeUI (or MUI_UI) and a modified ui file to add new buttons but this example adds the button at run-time...
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 2 ; Find cancel button
System::Call *(i,i,i,i)i.r1
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(ir0,ir1)'
System::Call *$1(i.r2,i.r3,i.r4,i.r5)
IntOp $5 $5 - $3 ;height
IntOp $4 $4 - $2 ;width
System::Call 'USER32::ScreenToClient(i$hwndparent,ir1)'
System::Call *$1(i.r2,i.r3)
System::Free $1
IntOp $2 $2 + $4 ;x
IntOp $2 $2 + 8  ;x+padding
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t "Button",t "Click Me",i${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_TABSTOP},ir2,ir3,ir4,ir5,i $hwndparent,i 0x666,i0,i0)i.r0'
SendMessage $hwndparent ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $1
SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETFONT} $1 1

GetFunctionAddress $0 onmybtnclick
ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler 0x666 $0
FunctionEnd

Function onmybtnclick
MessageBox mb_ok "You clicked me!"
FunctionEnd

Page Directory
Page Instfiles

Section
SectionEnd
```

And also this button appears on all screen How can I display only in one screen.

Comment: Are you using the Modern UI? The button position are not the same, that is probably why it ends up in the wrong place.

Comment: Please post your full code next time, this code is missing `!include MUI.nsh` or `Function .onGuiInit`!

Comment: NSIS is the opposite of Windows Installer.  Tag removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$2` and `$3` before the call to CreateWindowEx to change the button position. You can save the handle to the button in another variable after CreateWindowEx but I just used the Id in this example (0x666).

```
Name BtnTest
Outfile test.exe
Installdir "$temp"
RequestExecutionLevel user
BrandingText " " ;Button covers this text
!include nsDialogs.nsh ;For WS_*
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT SKIP
/**/ !include MUI2.nsh #*/
!ifndef MUI_INCLUDED
Function .onGuiInit
Call SKIP
FunctionEnd
!endif

Function SKIP
; You are supposed to use ChangeUI (or MUI_UI) and a modified ui file to add new buttons but this example adds the button at run-time...
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 2 ; Find cancel button
System::Call *(i,i,i,i)i.r1
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(ir0,ir1)'
System::Call *$1(i.r2,i.r3,i.r4,i.r5)
IntOp $5 $5 - $3 ;height
IntOp $4 $4 - $2 ;width
System::Call 'USER32::ScreenToClient(i$hwndparent,ir1)'
System::Call *$1(i.r2,i.r3)
System::Free $1
!ifdef MUI_INCLUDED
StrCpy $2 15 ; Whatever you feel looks good
!else
IntOp $2 $2 + $4 ;x
IntOp $2 $2 + 8  ;x+padding
!endif
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t "Button",t "Click Me",i${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_TABSTOP},ir2,ir3,ir4,ir5,i $hwndparent,i 0x666,i0,i0)i.r0'
SendMessage $hwndparent ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $1
SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETFONT} $1 1

GetFunctionAddress $0 onmybtnclick
ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler 0x666 $0
FunctionEnd

Function onmybtnclick
MessageBox mb_ok "You clicked me!"
FunctionEnd

Function HideIt
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 0x666
ShowWindow $0 0
FunctionEnd
Function ShowIt
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 0x666
ShowWindow $0 1
FunctionEnd

!ifdef MUI_INCLUDED
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW HideIt
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW ShowIt
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW HideIt
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
!else
Page Components "" HideIt
Page Components "" ShowIt
Page Components "" HideIt
Page Instfiles
!endif

Section
SectionEnd
```

Comment: I have custome pages , like you have mentioned in else loop. But the code inside else loop is not executing...  I have in else loop this snippet -  Page custom "MailSetUp" "Mail"  where MailSetUP is an ini file. here ShowIt does't work . Can you please help me.

Comment: Call ShowIt at the start of MailSetUp

Comment: Yes I tried this before MailSetup as in page custom snippet below but in this scenario MailSetup screen itself is not show and button is displayed on next screen i.e in DSetup screen. custom screen code is-  Page custom ShowIt "MailSetUp" "Mail" and  Page custom "DBSetup" "Validate"

Comment: When using a custom page you cannot put ShowIt in the page instruction, add "call ShowIt" to the MailSetup function...

Comment: Note: This code is not MUI compatible because the Cancel button is on the other side of the window. Set $2 to a small value or use the code I posted @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/53785305/3501