# New customized Print button in the NSIS installer screen is not displaying

Tags: nsis

My requirement is,

I wanted to add a new button ("Print") to the License Agreement custom screen. For this I have written the below code. It is compiling but is not showing the "Print" button.

Please help me to resolve this. And also is there any simplest way to create a new button on the installer screen?

```
; Pages

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

;Customizing the License Page Text
!define MUI_TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE "End-User License Agreement"
!define MUI_TEXT_LICENSE_SUBTITLE "Please read the following license agreement carefully"
!define MUI_INNERTEXT_LICENSE_BOTTOM ""
!define MUI_INNERTEXT_LICENSE_TOP ""
!define MUI_INNERTEXT_LICENSE_BOTTOM_CHECKBOX ""
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LICENSESHOW MyLicenseShowCallback

Function MyLicenseShowCallback

; You are supposed to use ChangeUI (or MUI_UI) and a modified ui file to add new buttons but this example adds the button at run-time...
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 2 ; Find cancel button
System::Call *(i,i,i,i)i.r1
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(ir0,ir1)'
System::Call *$1(i.r2,i.r3,i.r4,i.r5)
IntOp $5 $5 - $3 ;height
IntOp $4 $4 - $2 ;width
System::Call 'USER32::ScreenToClient(i$hwndparent,ir1)'
System::Call *$1(i.r2,i.r3)
System::Free $1
IntOp $2 $2 + $4 ;x
IntOp $2 $2 + 8  ;x+padding
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i 0,t "Button",t "Print",i ${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_TABSTOP},i r2,i r3,i r4,i r5,i $hwndparent,i 0x666,i 0,i 0)i.r0'

SendMessage $hwndparent ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $1
SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETFONT} $1 1

GetFunctionAddress $0 onmybtnclick
ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler 0x666 $0

SendMessage $mui.LicensePage.Text ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(MUI_TEXT_LICENSE_TITLE)"

FunctionEnd

Function onmybtnclick
MessageBox mb_ok "You clicked me!"
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Your code does not even include a license page! Post your real code.

Comment: You are not supposed to create multiple Stackoverflow accounts, you have 3 already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For this I have written the below code

Are you sure about that? Looks a lot like the code **I** wrote in [a answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443901/3501).

You failed to properly read the MUI documentation and you failed to properly adapt the example code you found.

`MyLicenseShowCallback` is never executed because you used the wrong define, the correct name is `MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW`.

The other problem is that the original code placed the new button next to the Cancel button in the classic NSIS UI but the Cancel button is in a different place in MUI and the button ends up off-screen.

This code just places the button on the left side of the UI

```
Var PrintBtn
!include MUI2.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW HidePrintButton
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW MyLicenseShowCallback
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE HidePrintButton
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function HidePrintButton
${IfThen} $PrintBtn P<> 0 ${|} SendMessage $PrintBtn ${WM_CLOSE} 0 0 ${|}
FunctionEnd

Function MyLicenseShowCallback
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 2 ; Find cancel button so we can copy its size and y position.
System::Call *(i,i,i,i)p.r1
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(pr0,pr1)'
System::Call *$1(i.r2,i.r3,i.r4,i.r5)
IntOp $5 $5 - $3 ;height
IntOp $4 $4 - $2 ;width
System::Call 'USER32::ScreenToClient(p$hwndparent,pr1)'
System::Call *$1(i.r2,i.r3)
System::Free $1
IntOp $2 $4 / 5 ; Calculate x padding based on the width but you can put any value you want in $2
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i 0,t "Button",t "Print",i ${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_TABSTOP},i r2,i r3,i r4,i r5,p $hwndparent,p 0x666,p 0,p 0)p.r0'
StrCpy $PrintBtn $0
SendMessage $hwndparent ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $1
SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETFONT} $1 1
GetFunctionAddress $0 onmybtnclick
ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler 0x666 $0
FunctionEnd

Function onmybtnclick
MessageBox mb_ok "You clicked me!"
FunctionEnd
```